# How to pass Docker CLI `--gpus` Options in Kubernetes or enable GPU support without installing `nvidia-docker2` (Docker 19.03)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rancher, nvidia-docker

I'm currently using Docker 19.03 and Kubernetes 1.13.5 and Rancher 2.2.4. Since 19.03, Docker has officially support natively NVIDIA GPUs just by passing `--gpus` option. Example (from [NVIDIA/nvidia-docker github](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/Installation-(Native-GPU-Support)#usage)):

```
 docker run --gpus all nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi
```

But in Kubernetes, there's no option to pass Docker CLI options. So if I need to run a GPU instance, I have to install `nvidia-docker2`, which is not convenient to use.

Is there anyway to pass the Docker CLI options or passing NVIDIA runtime without installing `nvidia-docker2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GPU's are scheduled](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-gpus/scheduling-gpus/) via [device plugins](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/device-plugins) in Kubernetes.

> The [official NVIDIA GPU device](https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin) plugin has the following requirements:
>
> - Kubernetes nodes have to be pre-installed with NVIDIA drivers.
> - Kubernetes nodes have to be pre-installed with [nvidia-docker 2.0](https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin#preparing-your-gpu-nodes)
> - nvidia-container-runtime must be configured as the [default runtime](https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin#preparing-your-gpu-nodes) for docker instead of runc.
> - NVIDIA drivers ~= 361.93

Once the nodes are setup GPU's become another resource in your spec like `cpu` or `memory`.

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: gpu-thing
    image: whatever
    resources:
      limits:
        nvidia.com/gpu: 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the helping, but in [this document](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker), the `nvidia-docker2` method is deprecated and that package will no longer be support in the future update. The NVIDIA document you gave above seems pretty outdated.

Comment: kubernetes is only validated against the versions of Docker that exist at the time the alphas are cut, sometimes not even the latest. v1.15 supports Docker 1.13.1 to 18.09.

Comment: Btw I'm using this method to schedule my GPU worker. I also using the containered driver by NVIDIA to make my cluster be more flexible. Thanks for your helping. Marked your answer as solved

Comment: @AperturePrometheus did you end up just installing nvidia-docker2 for your kubernetes 1.13 setup?

Comment: @yee379 yeah, no other choice at the moment. This feature is too new so it may take a lot of time for kubernetes to adapt.